# Storing Sampled Data in an array

Tags: arrays, r, storing-data

```
 No.       Austria Germany Hungary Poland Spain Italy Portugal Slovenia Belgium France Netherlands Switzerland  UK Norway Denmark Sweden
    1       4.4     4.3     6.8    5.7   4.4   4.6      4.6      4.8     4.4    4.4         4.4         3.0 5.1    4.9     4.4    4.3
    2       4.3     4.2     6.7    5.7   4.4   4.6      4.5      4.7     4.4    4.4         4.3         3.1 5.0    4.8     4.4    4.2
    3       4.4     4.3     6.6    5.6   4.4   4.6      4.5      4.6     4.4    4.4         4.4         3.0 5.0    4.9     4.4    4.3
    4       4.2     4.1     6.7    5.7   4.2   4.4      4.4      4.4     4.3    4.2         4.2         2.9 4.7    4.8     4.2    4.2
    5       4.3     4.2     6.9    5.9   4.3   4.5      4.5      4.5     4.4    4.3         4.3         3.1 4.7    4.7     4.3    4.3
    6       4.2     4.0     7.1    5.8   4.2   4.4      4.3      4.4     4.3    4.2         4.1         2.9 4.5    4.5     4.1    4.1
    7       4.2     4.0     7.6    5.8   4.1   4.4      4.3      4.3     4.2    4.1         4.0         3.1 4.6    4.4     4.1    4.0
    8       4.1     3.8     8.4    6.0   4.1   4.4      4.4      4.3     4.1    4.0         4.0         3.0 4.4    4.3     4.0    3.9
    9       4.3     4.0     8.0    6.0   4.3   4.5      4.5      4.5     4.4    4.3         4.2         3.2 4.6    4.5     4.3    4.1
    10      4.5     4.2     8.1    6.1   4.4   4.7      4.6      4.6     4.5    4.4         4.4         3.3 4.9    4.6     4.4    4.2
```

This fictitious data of 16 European countries can be written in a multivariate form by constituting `q=4` regions: `Region-1 (Austria,Germany,Hungry,Poland)`, `Region-2 (Spain, Italy, Portugal, Slovenia)`, `Region-3 (Belgium,France,Netherlands,Switzerland)`, and `Region-4 (UK, Norway, Denmark, Sweden)`.

For the above data, I want to draw `N=100` bootstrap samples of size `n=5` rows and store the sampled data in a 4-dimensional array `DAT` of the order `(n*p*q*N)` where `p=4` is the number of countries and `q=4` is the number of regions.

I am using following code:

```
DATA16 <- read.table("20160302.txt",header=TRUE)
n <- 5; p <- 4; q <- 4; N <- 100
DAT    <- array(data=NA,dim=c(n,p,q,N))

for(i in 1:N){
for(j in 1:q){
for(k in 1:p){
            DAT[,,,i] <- DATA16[sample(10,n,replace=TRUE),]
}
}
}
```

This code gives an error

```
Error in DAT[, , , i] <- DATA16[sample(100, n, replace = TRUE), ] : 
  incorrect number of subscripts
```

How can I correct this code? Please help me.

Comment: Have you inspected the dimensions of `DATA16[sample(100, n, replace = TRUE), ]` and `DAT[, , , i]`? I don't think that fits. Maybe try `DAT[,,,i] <- array(unlist(DATA16[sample(10,n,replace=TRUE),-1]), dim=dim(DAT[,,,i]))`?

Comment: your suggested code is working but it is missing the samples from first country (Austria) and second the sampled values are mixed. I want to be sure that my sampled observations are from appropriate country and correct region. By the way, thanks @lukeA

Comment: I have tried by deleting -1, but still second problem remains the same. @lukeA